# Enabling Keycloak for specific Spring profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm new to Keycloak. I am trying to secure with Keycloak my REST application. The app contains several Spring profiles, which differ in configuration, workflow and exposed REST methods. How can I enable Keycloak only for specific profiles? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using SpringBoot 2.5.4

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

The application.properties file will look like:

```
spring.profiles.active=staging

#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
keycloak.enabled = false

#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=staging
keycloak.realm = demorealm
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.resource = demoapp
keycloak.credentials.secret = 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
```

The documentation on configuring keycloak for springboot is:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter

---

> 2.1.6. Spring Boot Adapter Edit this section Report an issue
>
> To be able to secure Spring Boot apps you must add the Keycloak Spring
> Boot adapter JAR to your app. You then have to provide some extra
> configuration via normal Spring Boot configuration
> (application.properties). Let’s go over these steps. Adapter
> Installation
>
> The Keycloak Spring Boot adapter takes advantage of Spring Boot’s
> autoconfiguration so all you need to do is add the Keycloak Spring
> Boot starter to your project.
>
> To add it using Maven, add the following to your dependencies:
>
> org.keycloak
>     keycloak-spring-boot-starter
>
> Add the Adapter BOM dependency:
>
> org.keycloak.bom
> keycloak-adapter-bom
> 15.0.2
> pom
> import
>
> Currently the following embedded containers are supported and do not
> require any extra dependencies if using the Starter:
>
> ```
> Tomcat
>
> Undertow
>
> Jetty
> ```
>
> Required Spring Boot Adapter Configuration
>
> This section describes how to configure your Spring Boot app to use
> Keycloak.
>
> Instead of a keycloak.json file, you configure the realm for the
> Spring Boot Keycloak adapter via the normal Spring Boot configuration.
> For example:
>
> keycloak.realm = demorealm keycloak.auth-server-url =
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth keycloak.ssl-required = external
> keycloak.resource = demoapp keycloak.credentials.secret =
> 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
> keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
>
> You can disable the Keycloak Spring Boot Adapter (for example in
> tests) by setting keycloak.enabled = false.
>
> To configure a Policy Enforcer, unlike keycloak.json,
> policy-enforcer-config must be used instead of just policy-enforcer.
>
> You also need to specify the Java EE security config that would
> normally go in the web.xml. The Spring Boot Adapter will set the
> login-method to KEYCLOAK and configure the security-constraints at
> startup time. Here’s an example configuration:
>
> keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = admin
> keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[1] = user
> keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = insecure
> stuff
> keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] =
> /insecure
>
> keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0] = admin
> keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].name = admin
> stuff
> keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] =
> /admin
>
> If you plan to deploy your Spring Application as a WAR then you
> should not use the Spring Boot Adapter and use the dedicated adapter
> for the application server or servlet container you are using. Your
> Spring Boot should also contain a web.xml file.